# Проблема при получении результата из serializers.serialize

Tags: python, json, django

Я получаю данные из таблицы следующим способом:

```
def get_users(request):
    users = User.objects.all()
    data = serializers.serialize('json', users)
    return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

И в ответ получаю следующее:

```
{"model": "api.user", "pk": 1, "fields": {"first_name": "Vlad", "second_name": "Sapozhnikov", "age": 21}}
```

Я не понимаю откуда берутся поля model, pk и fields и есть ли вообще способ получать json без них? Заранее благодарю за ответ, в Django я новичок.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83908/discussion-on-question-by--------s).

Answer (score 1):

так работает стандартный сериалайзер Django. Если надо получить "чистый" json, то можно написать так:

```
import json
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict
from django.http import HttpResponse
from main.models import User

def get_users(request):
    users = User.objects.all()
    data = json.dumps([model_to_dict(obj) for obj in users])
    return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: Я уже нашел решение, но все равно спасибо вам за ответ!